# Скрыть горизонтальную прокрутку но оставить возможность прокрутки

Tags: html, css

Есть следующий код

```
 <div class="test">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore, libero. Sit voluptatibus voluptate minus, voluptatem aut! Quod dolorem, quis modi, sed nobis necessitatibus quam cum aspernatur, quidem iste expedita alias.
        </p>
    </div>
```

Стили:

```
.test {
    width: 65%;
    display: inline-flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Как скрыть горизонтальный скролл но оставить возможность скролла при нажатии мышкой на текст и вращении вправо/влево?

Comment: К сожалению такое при помощи html + css не сделать. Вам придется писать свои обработчики на JS. В CSS укажите overflow: hiden, чтобы блок текста обрезался. Затем вам будет необходимо повесить обработчик события нажатой кнопки мыши ('mousedown'), внутри которого вы будете назначать обработчик на 'mousewheel' в котором будете считывать направление прокрутки колеса и сдвигать блок с текстом в сторону, относительно прокрутки, предварительно, путем подсчета разницы в ширине блоков, проверяя что блок не показан полностью. По событию 'mouseup' этот обработчик вращения колеса будите удалять.

Comment: @Gonzo а есть уже готовое на jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>


        * {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .test {
            width: 200px;
            display: inline-flex;
            white-space: nowrap;
            cursor: default;
            overflow: hidden;
            user-select: none;
        }
    </style>

    <!--    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload-->
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            let lastX = 0;
            let el = document.getElementById("el");

            let ok = false;
            el.onmousedown = function (e) {
                ok = true;
            };
            document.onmouseup = function (e) {
                ok = false;
            };
            document.onmousemove = function (e) {
                if (ok) el.scrollLeft -= e.clientX - lastX;
                lastX = e.clientX;
            }

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="test" id="el">
    <p>
        Lorem isum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore, libero. Sit voluptatibus voluptate minus,
        voluptatem aut! Quod dolorem, quis modi, sed nobis necessitatibus quam cum aspernatur, quidem iste expedita
        alias.
        <a href="google.com">feawfeaf</a>
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

или

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        .test {
            width: 200px;
            display: inline-flex;
            white-space: nowrap;
            cursor: default;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        body {
            width: 10000px;
            height: 10000px;
        }
    </style>

    <!--    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload-->
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            let lastX = 0;
            let el = document.getElementById("el");

            let ok = false;
            el.onmousedown = function (e) {
                ok = true;
            };
            el.onmouseup = function (e) {
                ok = false;
            };
            el.onmousemove = function (e) {
                if (ok) el.scrollLeft += e.clientX - lastX;
                lastX = e.clientX;
            }

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="test" id="el">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore, libero. Sit voluptatibus voluptate minus,
        voluptatem aut! Quod dolorem, quis modi, sed nobis necessitatibus quam cum aspernatur, quidem iste expedita
        alias.
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

или

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <style>
            .test {
                width: 200px;
                display: inline-flex;
                white-space: nowrap;
                cursor: default;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            body{
                width:  10000px;
                height: 10000px;
            }
        </style>

<!--    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload-->
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load',  function(){
        let lastX=0;
        let el = document.getElementById("el");
        let ok=false;

        el.onmousemove = function(e){
            if(ok) el.scrollLeft+=e.clientX - lastX;
            lastX = e.clientX;
        };
            document.body.onmouseup= function(e){
                ok=e.target!=document.body;
            };

       });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="test" id="el">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore, libero. Sit voluptatibus voluptate minus,
        voluptatem aut! Quod dolorem, quis modi, sed nobis necessitatibus quam cum aspernatur, quidem iste expedita
        alias.
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```